# Ubuntu install in VMware Workstation12

Tags: boot

When I installed Ubuntu 17.10 in VMware Workstation 12, I got the error message SMBus controller not enabled.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The message is true: the virtual hardware does not even have a [System Management Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Bus). It's not an error, it's purely informational.

If you don't want to see it for esthetic reasons you can always [blacklist the SMBus driver](https://whitehatty.com/2012/09/30/vmware-fusion-5-fix-ubuntu-linux-12-04-host-smbus-controller-not-enabled/), by adding `blacklist i2c-piix4` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.